# c++ how to include (circular dependency)?

Tags: c++

I have Environment.h file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "interfaces.h"

#ifndef ENVIRONMENT_H
#define ENVIRONMENT_H

class Environment {};
#endif
```

and i have Interfaces.h file:

```
#ifndef INTERFACES_H
#define INTERFACES_H

class IMoving {
    public: 
        virtual void Move() = 0;          
};

#endif
```

in interface IMoving i would like to get an Environment class, to know how to move

```
class IMoving {
    public: 
        virtual void Move(Environment*) = 0;          
};
```

if i want to do this i need to include environment.h

```
#include "Environment.h"
```

and here i'm getting an error, becouse Environment.h - includes Interfaces.h and Interfaces.h - includes Environtment.h. So how to make it work ?

**Sorry for spelling mistakes**

Comment: You are asking "So how to make it work?". Could you please, be more specific? Background: Is is working if you can include Environtment.h in Interfaces.h and vice versa? Is this what you want to achieve? I just want to make sure whether I can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [circular dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) one can use Forward declaration(s)

In Interfaces.h just above interface definition, forward declare `Environment` as follows:

```
class Environment;
```

Then when you implement IMoving in a class, you will include Environment.h in its implementation (cpp) file.

You can read more about Forward declaration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration).

Comment: @OzairKafay: This does not answer the question because the question seems to be about circular dependecies in terms of file inclusion by the C++ preprocessor - which the title already suggests.

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann I did not really get your objection to my answer! One thing is that this is a 9 year old question, and the op accepted it at that time.  Also, the only other answer is also suggesting forward declaration. 
However, I reviewing it again still makes me to say that he should forward declare Environment in the Interface.h and `include` Environment.h in cpp.

Comment: @OzairKafay: May be your answer fits to the questioners intended purpose - but then the question should be edited. When answers fit to questions after 9 Years - then they are still helpful. The misconception in the question is "cyclic include" in conjunction with constructions like #ifndef XYZ #define XYZ. From my experience, this will never work. The title refers to include and not to declaration.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @JörgBrüggmann. Would this be a better title: "How to declare classes to avoid circular dependencies?"?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you misspelled the class name a few times (Environtment,Envrirontment). Could that be the origin of your issue?

Otherwise I typically use the [Forwarded Declaration](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml)